# How can I override javascript click event for only certain elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anime.js

I'm working off of a tutorial from codrops.  There is a hover event for each item, as well as a click event that triggers an anime.js function.

I'm trying to work this so certain items (grid cells) don't trigger the anime.js function when clicked, but the hover function still works.

I've tried simple css pointer-events, but that disables the hover function.

I've constructing the two groups as separate items in JS, but then the animation doesn't work the same (it staggers the two different classes).

I've tried things to stop the default javascript behavior, but it seems to have no impact on the code.

Help!!!

I've made a functioning codepen - in the option there I'm trying to disable click event for any grid item with the id="noClick" - to no avail.

```
$('noClick').observe('click', function(event) {
    Event.stop(event); 
});
```

This is the primary function that creates the event

```
this.DOM.items.forEach((item, pos) => {
                // The item's title.
                const title = item.dataset.title;
                // Show the title next to the cursor.
                item.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => cursor.setTitle(title));
                item.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    // Position of the clicked item
                    this.pos = pos;
                    this.title = title;
                    // Start the effect and show the content behind
                    this.showContent();
                    // Force to show the title next to the cursor (it might not update because of the grid animation - the item under the mouse can be a different one than the one the user moved the mouse to)
                    cursor.setTitle(title);
                });
            });
```

where 'item' is

```
this.DOM.grid = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.grid');
            // Thr grid items
            this.DOM.items = [...this.DOM.grid.children];
            // totla number of grid items
            this.itemsTotal = this.DOM.items.length;
```

I've tried to create multiple items

```
 this.DOM.grid = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.grid');
            this.DOM.yesClick = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.yes-click'); 
            this.DOM.yesClickTwo = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.yes-click-2');            
            this.DOM.noClick = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.no-click');

            // Thr grid items
            this.DOM.items = [...this.DOM.yesClick.children, ...this.DOM.yesClickTwo.children];
            this.DOM.itemsNo = [...this.DOM.noClick.children];
            this.DOM.allItems = [...this.DOM.noClick.children, ...this.DOM.yesClick.children, ...this.DOM.yesClickTwo.children];


            // totla number of grid items
            this.itemsTotal = this.DOM.allItems.length;
```

This works, but messes with the animaton.

[Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/pixelgirl1111/pen/vYYVbYx)

I feel this is really simple and I'm missing something.   Looking to learn, so a push in the right direction or any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You have multiple elements with the same ID. But ID attribute must be unique.

**2.** You used `$('noClick')`, but ID selector would look like `#noClick`

If you want to mark few elements, use a class and select them like `.elementclass`. It is possible for element to have multiple classes, separated by space.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried changing the noClick to a class for the chosen grid items, and fixed the selector, but still no luck :( . its updated on the [codepen](https://codepen.io/pixelgirl1111/pen/vYYVbYx)

Comment: Now, your selector works (add `alert('')` or `console.log('')` to check. 

But you have many click handlers in different places.

Comment: Maybe you need to rethink how you place them? I suggest reading something about event bubbling/propagation, remove click handlers from divs and put a single click handler on their parent element instead and handle event there.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector doesn't seem correct so you either need #noClick or .noClick as the selector however you can stop the javascript from bubbling like this :-

```
$(".noClick").click(function(e) {
   // Do something?
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried fixing that on the codepen, but it still seems to be bubbling up :( [codepen](https://codepen.io/pixelgirl1111/pen/vYYVbYx)